# Why is this code not logging my message 5 times to conosle (I have used built-in javascript functions)?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, built-in, clearinterval

Expected output:
Here is message 1
Here is message 2
Here is message 3
Here is message 4
Here is message 5

Actual output:
Here is message 1
Here is message 2
Here is message 3
Here is message 4

```
let i = 1;
const myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Here is message ' + i);
    i = i + 1;
}, 2000);

// clear interval after specified time
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 10000);
```

[output on running code snippet using firefox web-browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQOOx.png)

Comment: Short answer is you can't predict the order that the js engine will add 5th function call to the event loop vs clearing the timer before it gets added. Read up on how asynchronous methods get added to event loop and how event loop works

Comment: Okay, Im new to js and programming, thanks will do that @charlietfl

Comment: Rather than use the `setTimeout` you would do better to clear the interval timer in the setInterval callback when `i` reaches 5

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, can you show me an example pls @charlietfl

Comment: Use a basic `if()` conditional ... `if(i===5){ clearInterval(myInterval);}`

Comment: okay got it, thank you very much charli

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code based on the comments above. I think your code has a valid purpose (with a couple tweaks) but i think it may not address the specific purpose of your problem or situation. Always try to look for the simplest solution. One thing i'll recommend is instead of doing `i = i + 1` you can just do `i++` if you are only incrementing by one.

```
let i = 1;
const max = 5;
const mytimer = setInterval(function () {
    if (i <= max) {
        console.log("Here is message " + i);
        i++;
    } else {
        console.log("end of timer");
        clearInterval(mytimer);
    }
}, 2000);
```